# Does it sense to use Ember 1.0RC1 with jQuery mobile in a single page web app?

Tags: jquery-mobile, ember.js

I've been trying to figure out the best way to use Rails, Ember 1.0RC and jQuery mobile but with no success.

I'm building a simple single web app with Rails as a backend that provides simple JSON. Now I know that Ember and JQM don't like each other and you have to write custom helpers to render Ember views. This makes things quite complicated.

I know that there are a few examples out there but they are quite obsolete since Ember was under heavy development and there have been many changes.

I'd like to hear from experienced developers if it is a good idea or not to use Ember with JQM in my case?

Maybe I should go for other MVC framework (which one?)?

Sorry for the question being pretty open but I could not find any reliable resources on the web.

// edited on March 20

I've watched 2 Ember screencasts (from Peepscode and Railscasts) and they shed some light on the matter. Now I know a little bit more. But let me explain what I'm after.

I'm building an internal 'kudos' app based on the merits system. That is every Monday an employee receives 20 'kudos' to give other co-workers. The design is as follows:
the main page shows a list of all employees and at the top, also as an list item, there is position that belongs to himself. It shows for example how many kudos to give left and how many he or she received from others. The owner? do not know how many kudos other employees received. But I think there'll be a 'Top 3 kudoers' page.

When you tap/hold an item, a modal dialog will appear that will ask you if you what to give a kudo.

It is done. But what remained is porting it to Ember.

Now, after watching screencasts I kind of know what to do, but what buggs me is how to make JQM internal hash pages and Ember router a breeze.

I saw that one page app in Ember uses urls like these:
myapp/#/users/user

whereas JQM uses internal pages like this:
myapp/#somepage

I'd like to keep the app as simple as possible (following Ember 'convention over configuration') and make use of JQM internal pages.

So my question is how can they both go with each other?

Comment: Maybe you could give an example for the problems, you are facing. I haven't used it myseld mit JQM, but my understanding always was, that it should be comfortable to integrate other frameworks.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer but now I think it is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to hear from experienced developers if it is a good idea or not to use Ember with JQM in my case?

I've been asking around about this and pretty much everyone who has tried to use JQuery Mobile with ember has advised against it.

Not that it can't be done. It's just that most people have determined the challenges outweigh the benefits. Especially if you are new to one or both frameworks.

The best example of JQM + Ember integration i've seen is by TOMASZ and can be found here: https://coderwall.com/p/ylogzg

Thing is, that app does not use ember router at all. For sure it won't help you **make JQM internal hash pages and Ember router a breeze**

Comment: Hi Mike! Actually Tomasz is my colleague and forked his project to make a better use of both frameworks. You can find it here: https://github.com/ryrych/ember_mobile

Now I've been tinkering around how to combine JQM internal hash pages and Ember router and hm, I don't know how to do it :(

So my question is what would you choose for a mobile app that could use Ember?